# IA32_MISC_ENABLE Register in C#. How to access

Tags: c#, windows, cpu-registers

I have been trying to workout how to access and set/clear IA32_MISC_ENABLE Register bits and in particular Turbo Boost ie: I believe toggling bit 38 of the IA32_MISC_ENABLE Register will turn Turbo Boost off or on. What I can't seem to find is how to access the Register from C#.

Sorry I have no Code to post as I don't even know where to start here, just some direction on where to start would be helpful. I have been Googling now for a week and can't seem to find any information or Code explaining this which is surprising.

Thanks
Danny

Comment: It is part of the power management settings on a microcontroller which can be set using windows dlls.  See pinvoke : https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/RegisterPowerSettingNotification.html  Here is the definition : https://xem.github.io/minix86/manual/intel-x86-and-64-manual-vol3/o_fe12b1e2a880e0ce-470.html

Comment: This may be better way of handling this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/performance-tuning/hardware/power/power-performance-tuning#processor-responsiveness-override

Comment: @jdweng From what you have shown me I'm going to look at CPUID. I don't think I can change these flags through CPUID (I could be wrong) but I might get a hint on how to proceed. Thanks